# Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-bin.zip'

Tags: java, gradle, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

Im using Eclipse Oxigen and I have a problem building a Gradle project with ArcGIS Java SDK Plug-in, the error I got is:

```
Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.
Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-bin.zip'.

A problem occurred configuring root project 'ArcGISPrimerApp'.
Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\Usuario\.arcgis\100.2.1\arcgis-java-resources-100.2.1.zip'.archive is not a ZIP archive org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-bin.zip'.
```

My build.gradle is this:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'
//apply the ArcGIS Java SDK Plug-in for Gradle With_3D-Add_Graphics-
Surface_Placement
apply plugin: 'com.esri.arcgisruntime.java'

buildscript {
repositories { maven { url 'https://esri.bintray.com/arcgis' } }
dependencies { classpath 'com.esri.arcgisruntime:gradle-arcgis-java-
plugin:1.0.0' }
}

arcgis.version = '100.2.1'

// download javadoc
eclipse.classpath.downloadJavadoc = true
```

What should I do in order to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure arcgis-java-resources-100.2.1.zip is a valid zip file? Have you tried opening it?

Comment: This is the guide https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/guide/develop-your-first-map-app-with-gradle.htm. Use Gradle is an option but you can develop downloading the SDK in ZIP with the jar files.